# Cross domain request of a third party API (https)

Tags: javascript, json, cors, cross-domain, jsonp

This is the url that I'm trying to get the JSON from: https://shopicruit.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=1&access_token=c32313df0d0ef512ca64d5b336a0d7c6

However, I have tried both CORS but it failed. Here is my code following from a template:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
  var url = 'https://shopicruit.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=1&access_token=c32313df0d0ef512ca64d5b336a0d7c6';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    console.log("success");
  };

  xhr.onerror = function () {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}
makeCorsRequest();
```

It still gives me this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load >https://shopicruit.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?>page=1&access_token=c32313df0d0ef512ca64d5b336a0d7c6. No 'Access-Control->Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' >is therefore not allowed access.

I also tried JSONP but it looks like it doesn't support JSONP.

Any help and insights will be appreciated!

Comment: You'll have to use a server-side proxy on a server you control if the site is not configured to allow cross-origin requests. There's nothing you can do from JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: And when @Pointy  mention proxy he meant this https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies

Comment: @Pointy Do you have a link to a tutorial that I can follow along?

Comment: @singard how about that link somebody posted in the comment above?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial this link looks like I need to setup an app on shopify?

Comment: You can set up a server-side proxy on any server you want; that's just one possibility. You've got some sort of server already serving up the page you're working on.

Comment: @Pointy ok cool thanks. Just wondering why didn't the CORS work in this case?

Comment: @singard the **server** has to be configured to allow it, and in this case the server is not so configured. By default, browsers do not allow cross-origin XHR. JSONP can work too, but again the server is in control and you cannot override that behavior from code in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurs because XMLHTTPRequest causes CORS issues. XMLHTTPRequest call should be made to same domain from browser.

https://shopicruit.myshopify.com has to implement **Access-Control-Allow-Origin : ***  header in the response in order to access from all domains.

Else you can use your server as a proxy.